# Prove that $\langle F,\bullet \rangle$ is a group where $F=\{f\mid f:X→G\}$ and $\langle G,\ast \rangle$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

> Let $\langle G,\ast \rangle$ be a group and $X$ be a set. We define $F$ to be the set of all the functions from $X$ to $G$, meaning $F=\{ f\mid f:X \rightarrow G\}$.
>   We define the operation $\bullet$ on the elements of $F$ by the following:
>   $$\forall f,g \in F, \forall x \in X: (f \bullet g)(x)=f(x)\ast g(x).$$
>   Prove that $\langle F,\bullet \rangle$ is a group.

I am a bit confused on how to prove *closure*, since the outcome of $(f \bullet g)(x)$ would be in $G$.

I hope that I am not missing something basic here, full solution, partial solution or even a hint on solving this question would be appreciated.

Comment: To prove closure, you must prove that $f \bullet g$ if a function from $X$ to $G$. The domain is clearly $X$, so what remains to prove is that for all $x \in X$, $(f \bullet g)(x) \in G$. Now use the definition of $\bullet$, that $f$ and $g$ are functions $X \to Y$, and that $G$ is a group (hence closed under its operation $*$).

Comment: $(f\bullet g)(x)$ may be an element of $G$, but $f\bullet g$ is a map from $X$ to $G$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now, solved!
Thanks everyone for the help.